# Where should I put my decorators?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

I tried to look for a similar question without luck. I'm quite new to python, so, please, be nice :)

I have my class, but I wanted to log when functions are executed and whit which parameters, so I wrote my decorators.

At moment I have everything in a single script, which looks more or less like:

```
import...

decorators...

my class...
```

Sincerely I don't like the decorators hanging outside of my class, I have a function to initialize the log level and a function which is never used as decorator, but it is used by the other decorators. [Code at the end of the question]

Should I put my decorators in a `decorator.py` file and import it in my class script? Should I leave them like that and learn to love this kind of file structure?

```
def initialize_log(db):
    logzero.loglevel(logging.INFO)
    logzero.logfile("sw-" + db + ".log")


def _log(log_function, f, *args, **kwargs):
    arguments = ""
    if len(args) > 1:
        arguments = " ({})".format(','.join(map(str, args[1:])))

    kwarguments = ""
    if len(kwargs) > 0:
        kwarguments = " ({})".format(','.join([str(k) + "=" + str(kwargs[k]) for k in kwargs]))

    log_function(f.__name__ + " started" + arguments + kwarguments)
    res = f(*args, **kwargs)
    log_function(f.__name__ + " completed" + arguments + kwarguments)
    return res


def log_info(f):
    def _decorator(*args, **kwargs):
        return _log(logger.info, f, *args, **kwargs)

    return _decorator


def log_debug(f):
    def _decorator(*args, **kwargs):
        return _log(logger.debug, f, *args, **kwargs)

    return _decorator
```

Comment: You can do any of those, but since all of these functions serve a common purpose it'd be more Pythonic to put them in a separate module. Also, you can wrap these in a class probably with a name like `AttrLogger` or smth. In this case you can create other decorator based classes with different functionality and all of them in your `decorator` module.